# How to print specific data in php from json output from server?

Tags: php, json, associative-array

This is the output I get when I try to access the $url directly in my browser.

{"message":"success","result":{"amount":0.43,"total_coins":4306,"currency_type":"Rs"},"return_code":200}

When I'm trying to access and print amount as "balance is $amount" in my php code I'm getting the output as 0. What could be the error?

```
    <?php
$url="http://localhost/account?id=c36571c7b2814c338b24c4c6e51098f1&secret_id=98bb36d4b4c1360ebd9a7386c74cbdb6&user_id=Tsa78/";
$jsonData = file_get_contents($url);

$arr = json_decode($jsonData,true);
$amount = $arr["result"]["amount"];``
echo "Balance is ". $amount;
?>
```

Comment: Use `json_decode` with second parameter set to true, then you will get an array instead of an object. (I am assuming you know how to handle nested associative arrays? If not, this would be the time that you go and find yourself a beginner tutorial on that then.)

Comment: Yeah I surely need to learn this but it would be nice if you could help me in this with the code sample?

Comment: Please share the code you are using such that others could spot the problem

Comment: I've shared the code snippet now.

Answer (score 0):

The first stap you need to take is to convert the JSON data to a php array.

The second step is selecting the data from the php array.

The last step is printing the data (for simplicity this is done by an echo statement).

The code below will print the amount.

```
<?php
$jsonData = '{"message":"success","result":{"amount":0.43,"total_coins":4306,"currency_type":"Rs"},"return_code":200}';

$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData, true);
$amount = $phpArray["result"]["amount"];

echo "Amount is ". $amount;

?>
```